# Can I force MSBuild to raise an error if a specific project or library is referenced?

Tags: msbuild, dependencies

We have a large, multi-project solution, that has a number of build configurations and output targets.

For various reasons, mainly to do with excessive references or additional files, I'd like to ensure that some of these projects are not updated to ever reference some of the other projects.

For example:

```
- Foundation.Common.Entities (Simple models, interfaces, etc.)
  - Foundation.Common (References Entities, has additional logic)
  - Foundation.XConnect.CustomTabs (More models, references Foundation.Common.Entities,
                                    must not reference Foundation.Common)
    - Project.Web (References all of the above)
```

I'd like to stop people referencing `Foundation.Common` in the `CustomTabs` project, as it has a number of additional references that must not be deployed to some of the targets that the `CustomTabs` DLL is deployed to.

As `CustomTabs` is also referenced further down the chain, I can't just create a separate solution for the `CustomTabs` tree.

I'm not adverse to dropping StyleCop or similar in, but would prefer a slightly more lightweight solution initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple target does the trick; add this into the `CustomTabs` project file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Error Condition="'%(ProjectReference.Name)' == 'Foundation.Common'"
         Text="Please don't reference Foundation.Common"/>
</Target>
```

This loops over all project references checking if the name matches and raises an error if so. The same principle works for `Reference.Identity` as well.